# Connection to AS400 ( DB2 iseries) using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm working on an android Application using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015. Our data is in AS400 systems. I'm trying to connect to the AS400 via DB2 using the iSeries.  I'm referencing the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll as I use this dll for my other web applications that work fine with DB2. I get the following error as soon as I try to create a new connection object: The type initializer for "IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2tracing" threw an exception. When I check the android device monitor is like it can't access any of the classes from the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll. Is unable to use this dll. Are there some kid of permissions that I am missing?  I'm also doing no linking so it includes all my dlls.

Thank you!

Comment: IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll is not a cross platform DLL.  You will need to access the database through a web service.

Answer (score 1):

AS/400 and iSeries are both names for an old IBM midrange system that is now called `IBM i on Power`. `IBM i` is the operating system, `Power Systems` is the hardware. The specific dialect of DB2 that runs under `IBM i` is `DB2 for i`. `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll` is the `DB2 for i` .NET provider for Windows. If you want to access `DB2 for i` from Android, the best thing might be a JDBC driver. You can get that at http://jt400.sourceforge.net/